# cómo puedo crear un "no circula" en consola con Ifs?

Tags: java

cómo puedo crear un "no circula" en consola con Ifs?
es decir, sólo necesito ingresar la terminación de la placa y que me diga qué día me toca descansar

Comment: Desgraciadamente tu pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que existen muchas respuestas posibles, seria bueno que agregaras lo que haz intentado para enfocar la pregunta a un método concreto, saludos.